# Effect of 4 options on one column of variables

Tags: logistic

```
Column 1 Column 2

1         56
3         18
3         27
2         31
4         22
1         32
2         65
4         39
```

How do I find out how much a 1,2,3 or 4 effects the variables in column 2?

I.e.  1's increase the dependent variable by X, 2's decrease by X, etc

Comment: You mean like a one-way ANOVA?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case for logistic regression, which is what you might use if your dependent variable were binary. Assuming you are willing to make the [assumptions underlying ordinary least-squares (OLS) regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions), you could model `Column 2` as a function of three categorical variables (assuming that `Column 1` is categorical...

e.g., if we say:
$X_1 = 1$  when `Column 1` is 1 and zero otherwise,
$X_2 = 1$  when `Column 1` is 2 and zero otherwise, $X_3 = 1$  when `Column 1` is 3 and zero otherwise, then we can use the following model:

$$ColumnTwo_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X1_i + \beta_2 X2_i + \beta_3 X3_i +\varepsilon_i$$

Here, our intercept term, $\beta_0$, would estimate the mean of `Column 2` when `Column 1` $= 4$, $\beta_1$ would estimate the difference between the mean values of `Column 2` when `Column 1` $= 4$ and $1$, and so on.

Note that there are many possible ways you could code your categorical predictors. The above approach is known as [dummy coding](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/dummy.htm), but it is not the only option.